# Calculate hour difference between two timestamps?

Tags: php, date, firebird

I'm working on a PHP project with Firebird, about working hours. Basically, every worker has a card, which he stamps on entering and leaving the building. Each stamp is recorded into the `ARCHIVE` table, with date (`DATUM`), id (`NREC`) and user_id (`NCODE`). What I have to do is get the last and first time of each day, and calculate hours. So to get the first and last, I used this:

```
SELECT MAX(NREC)
FROM ARCHIVE
WHERE DATUM BETWEEN '$day.$month.$year' AND '$day+1.$month.$year';

SELECT MIN(NREC)
FROM ARCHIVE
WHERE DATUM BETWEEN '$day.$month.$year' AND '$day+1.$month.$year';
```

I save both max and max in a variable, then I select the both dates and calculate. But that are 4 queries. Is there any simpler/easier way?
Also, `DATUM` is a timestamp

Comment: I think your question needs a little more detail on what information you exactly need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try:

```
SELECT DATUM FROM ARCHIVE JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(NREC) AS minid, MAX(NREC) as maxid FROM ARCHIVE 
    WHERE DATUM  DATUM BETWEEN '$day.$month.$year' AND '$day+1.$month.$year' 
    AND NCODE = user_id) 
as mm ON mm.maxid = ARCHIVE.NREC OR mm.minid=ARCHIVE.NREC
```

If Firebird works anything like MySQL this should give you two timestamps.

Comment: That is the problem - FireBird is not like MySQL, which is why I've been having problems EDIT: But that works, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT CAST(DATUM AS DATE), MAX(NREC), MIN(NREC)
FROM ARCHIVE
GROUP BY 1
```

Optionally combined with a condition for the right date range?